# Find a map $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to prove surjectivity for a given $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

When the following is given:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ be given by $f(x)=(4x, -x)$ for all $x \in 
> \mathbb{R}$
>
> 1. How to find a map $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g\circ f$ is surjective and give proof that this holds.
> 2. Find a function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\circ g$ is injective and give proof that g does satisfy the given condition.

What I did so far:

> $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ $f(x)=(4x, -x)$
>
> $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ =?
>
> $g\circ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so $g\circ f(x) = g(4x, -x)$ which must be surjective
>
> If I use $g(x)= x-y =g(f(x))$ than $g\circ f(x)=4x+x=5x$ which is surjective

Can someone please tell me if this is right and help me to show how this holds for the second part?
Thanks!

Comment: You should formulate more carefully. Being surjective or injective is a property of a mapping between sets, not a property of a number or expression. So instead of "$5x$ is surjective" (which does not mean anything) it should be: the function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $x\mapsto5x$ is surjective".

Answer (score 2):

This is all well and good. There are a couple of possibilities for $g$ which might be even simpler to work with, though. For instance $g(x,y) =x/4$ or $g(x,y)=-y$, but it matters little.

As for the surjectivity, you just have to point out that for any $c\in\Bbb R$ there is an $x$ such that
$$
c=g\circ f(x) =5x
$$
and that $x$ is, for your $g$, given by $c/5$.

Comment: Thanks! But what about the second part? I guess I have to prove $f(g(x))=(4g(x), -g(x))$=injective. What is the best way to do this?